# How to know what Congress will be voting on?

Tags: united-states, congress

I've been trying to search for a type of schedule that will show what Congress will be voting on but can't seem to find any answers. How are the bills that Congress will vote on/discuss per day decided and where can I find out what bills will be voted on per week?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Senate, chamber leadership get to decide what comes up for discussion each day (see this [CRS article](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/common/briefing/Senate_legislative_process.htm#3) on the Senate's website):

> The Senate accords its majority leader prime responsibility for scheduling. He may carry out this responsibility by moving that the Senate proceed to consider a particular matter. By precedent, he and the minority leader are recognized preferentially, and by custom only he (or his designee) makes motions or requests affecting when the Senate will meet and what it will consider.

The Government Publishing Office maintains daily calendars which can tell you all the items which *may* be considered that day (here's a [link](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/browse/collection.action?collectionCode=CCAL&browsePath=115%2FSCAL%2F2017-09%2F09-18%5C%2F2%3BDAILY&isCollapsed=false&leafLevelBrowse=false&isDocumentResults=true&ycord=57) to the Senate calendar).  You are probably interested in the General Orders section, which lists the topics which may be considered on the floor. There are other sections for committees (including conference committees).

Which actual items are discussed is at the discretion of the majority leader.

Although the House's rules are slightly different, the answer is the same: you can find a link to their daily calendar on the GPO website [here](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CCAL-115hcal-2017-09-18/content-detail.html).

Comment: Awesome, looks to be what I'm looking for! Quick question if you have a chance though, I only see September 18th listed on the link provided but no other dates for Sep, does this get updated daily for the following week or something?

Comment: It should be updated each day. So at the end of the day on the 18th there should be a listing for the 19th. They can't really do it any sooner than that, because some things may be added/removed from the list during the 18th.

Comment: https://www.majorityleader.gov/daily-schedule/ might be too real time especially given the comments, but is interesting.